# get input in python script from a file

Tags: python, input, email-validation

I am trying to write a script in python which takes input from a file, which is a list of usernames, and run `VRFY` command for smtp server. Below is the script.

I am a almost new to python. I was able to create the below script with help from internet. In this script in have to run the script with a particular username.

How can I provide a file which includes a list of usernames and the script performs `VRFY` for each of the user in the file?

```
!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "usage: vrfy.py <username>"
        sys.exit(0)

#create socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#connect to the server 
connect=s.connect(('10.10.10.10',25))
#REceive the banner
banner=s.recv(1024)
print banner
#VRFY a user
s.send('VRFY ' + sys.argv[1] + '\r\n')
result=s.recv(1024)
print result
#close the socket
s.close
```

thanks,

Comment: Thank you so much gentlemen. Really appreciate your help. Thanks sk11, thanks Dominik. Sk11 could you please let me know that does the following code do exactly. for u in users:
    user = u.strip()

Comment: `strip()` basically removes the whitespaces from the string. Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). When you read the lines from the file, all entries will contain the `'\n'`, `strip()` will remove all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `users.txt` contains the usernames, something like below will do the job.

```
!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

# Probably u don't need it now
#if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    #print "usage: vrfy.py <username>"
    #sys.exit(0)

with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
    users = f.readlines()

#create socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#connect to the server 
connect=s.connect(('10.10.10.10',25))
#Receive the banner
banner=s.recv(1024)
print banner

for u in users:
    user = u.strip()

    #VRFY a user
    s.send('VRFY ' + user + '\r\n')
    result=s.recv(1024)
    print result

#close the socket
s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open a file in Python by using `open()`. I assume your text file full of user names looks like this:

```
# usernames.txt
paul
henry
jim
foo
```

In your script you can open the file like this and read in one line at a time:

```
usernames_file = open('usernames.txt')
for line in usernames_file:
    # get rid of the <end line> character at the end of each line
    username = line.strip()
    print username
```

Comment: `strip()` (or `rstrip()`) is more commonly used to remove (trailing) whitespace characters instead of `line[:-1]`.